# Issue in Adding property to string object

Tags: javascript

```
var s = "Hi";

Date.now = function (){
    return new Date();
}

s.createdOn = function (){
    return new Date();
}

alert(s.createdOn()); // This is not working
alert(Date.now()); // This works fine
```

Am i violating any rule. Because i can add new property to Date class but not to string class. why?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you would want to extend specifically string in this way? A custom object might be a better fit and more logical.

Comment: I am just curious to know why it s not working. No any specific reason

Comment: Ok, then @UNNI has provided a very good explanation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't add properties or methods to a string literal is that when you try to access a literal's property or method, the Javascript interpreter temporarily copies the value of the string into a new object and then use that object's properties or methods. This means a String literal can only access a string's default properties or methods and those that have been added as prototypes.

More info can be obtained from this link:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference

Hope this will help you

---

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
var s = "Hi";
```

with

```
var s = {};
```

Comment: May i know how t make diffence?

Comment: it's explained with @UNNI's answer. and why are you appending methods to a string anyway?

Comment: am just curious to know why it s not working. No any specific reason